# playframework scala Seq[Future[Model]] removing the Future

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have the following issue,

I have a `Seq[Future[ProcessStepTemplatesModel]]` and I want to remove the inner Future.

What I excpected to get is a `Seq[ProcessStepTemplatesModel]`.

The complete code looks like this

```
Future.sequence {
        processSteps.map { step => // This is a "for each" over a Seq[ProcessStepTemplatesModel]
            val prerequisiteFuture = processStepPrerequisitesDTO.getProcessStepPrerequisiteProcessTemplateIds(step.id.get)

            prerequisiteFuture.map(prereqTemplates => {

             processTemplateDTO.getProessTemplatesForStepPreqrequsites(prereqTemplates).map(pres => {
                 step.stepPrerequisites ++Some(pres)
                 step
                })

            })
        }
      }
```

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

```
def getEditProcessTemplateData(processTemplateId: Int) = Action.async {
    //Get all steps of this process templates
    val stepIds: Future[Seq[Int]] = processTemplateDTO.getProcessStepTemplateIds(processTemplateId)

    val process = for {
      allApprovedProcessTemplates <- processTemplateDTO.getApprovedProcessTemplates //Get all approved process templates
      processTemplate <- processTemplateDTO.getProcessTemplate(processTemplateId) // Get the Process Template
      prerequisites <- getProcessTemplateForEdit(processPrerequisitesDTO.getProcessPrerequisiteProcessTemplateIdsByProcessTemplateId(processTemplateId))
      postConditions <- getProcessTemplateForEdit(processPostConditionsDTO.getProcessPostConditionProcessTemplateIdsByProcessTemplateId(processTemplateId))
      approvedProcessTemplate <- processTemplateDTO.getProcessTemplate(processTemplate.get.approveprocess)
      trainedProcessTemplate <- processTemplateDTO.getProcessTemplate(processTemplate.get.trainingsprocess)
      processSteps <- processTemplateDTO.getProcessStepTemplates(processTemplateId)
      // Step prerequisites
      processStepsPrerequisites <- getProcessStepsPrerequisites(stepIds)
      processStepsPrerequisiteProcessTemplate <- getProcessStepsPrerequisiteProcessTemplate(stepIds)
      processTemplatesForStepPrerequisites <- getProcessTemplateForStepPrerequisite(stepIds)
      // Step post conditions
      processStepsPostConditions <- getProcessStepsPostConditions(stepIds)
      processStepPostConditionProcessTemplate <- getProcessStepPostConditionProcessTemplate(stepIds)
      processTemplatesForStepPostConditions <- getProcessTemplateForStepPostCondition(stepIds)
      // Derived processes
      derivedProcesses <- getDerivedProcesses(stepIds)
      processTemplatesForStepDerivedProcesses <- getProcessStepsDerivedProcesses(stepIds)
      // Process to process step
      processStepsTemplates_ProcessTemplates <- getProcessStepsTemplates_ProcessTemplates(stepIds)
      processTemplatesForProcessTemplatesToProcessStep <- getProcessTemplateToProcessStepId(stepIds)
      responsible <- raciProcessTemplateDTO.getResponsibleProcessTemplates(processTemplateId) // get all responsibles for this process template
      accountable <- raciProcessTemplateDTO.getAccountableProcessTemplates(processTemplateId) // get all accountables for this process template
      consulted <- raciProcessTemplateDTO.getConsultedProcessTemplates(processTemplateId) // get all consulted for this process template
      informed <- raciProcessTemplateDTO.getInformedProcessTemplates(processTemplateId) // get all consulted for this process template
    } yield (allApprovedProcessTemplates, processTemplate, prerequisites, postConditions, processSteps, processStepsPrerequisites,
      processStepsPrerequisiteProcessTemplate, processTemplatesForStepPrerequisites, processStepsPostConditions, processStepPostConditionProcessTemplate, processTemplatesForStepPostConditions, derivedProcesses,
      processTemplatesForStepDerivedProcesses, processStepsTemplates_ProcessTemplates, processTemplatesForProcessTemplatesToProcessStep, approvedProcessTemplate, trainedProcessTemplate, responsible, accountable, consulted, informed)

    process.flatMap({ case (allApprovedProcessTemplates, processTemplate, prerequisites, postConditions, processSteps, processStepsPrerequisites,
    processStepsPrerequisiteProcessTemplate, processTemplatesForStepPrerequisites, processStepsPostConditions, processStepPostConditionProcessTemplate, processTemplatesForStepPostConditions, derivedProcesses,
    processTemplatesForStepDerivedProcesses, processStepsTemplates_ProcessTemplates, processTemplatesForProcessTemplatesToProcessStep, approvedProcessTemplate, trainedProcessTemplate, responsible, accountable, consulted, informed) =>

      Future.sequence {
        processSteps.map {
          step =>
            val prerequisiteFuture = processStepPrerequisitesDTO.getProcessStepPrerequisiteProcessTemplateIds(step.id.get)

            prerequisiteFuture.map(prereqTemplates => {

              processTemplateDTO.getProessTemplatesForStepPreqrequsites(prereqTemplates).map(pres => {
                  println("test", pres) // they are printed
                  step.stepPrerequisites ++Some(pres)
                  println("test2", step)
                 step
                })

            })
        }
      }.map {
        stepTemplates =>
          Ok(Json.obj(
            "allApprovedProcessTemplates" -> allApprovedProcessTemplates,
            "processTemplate" -> processTemplate,
            "prerequisites" -> prerequisites,
            "postConditions" -> postConditions,
            "approvedProcessTemplate" -> approvedProcessTemplate,
            "trainedProcessTemplate" -> trainedProcessTemplate,
            // Step prerequisites
            "processStepsPrerequisites" -> processStepsPrerequisites,
            "processStepsPrerequisiteProcessTemplate" -> processStepsPrerequisiteProcessTemplate,
            "processTemplatesForStepPrerequisites" -> processTemplatesForStepPrerequisites,
            // Step post conditions
            "processStepsPostConditions" -> processStepsPostConditions,
            "processStepPostConditionProcessTemplate" -> processStepPostConditionProcessTemplate,
            "processTemplatesForStepPostConditions" -> processTemplatesForStepPostConditions,
            // Derived processes
            "derivedProcesses" -> derivedProcesses,
            "processTemplatesForStepDerivedProcesses" -> processTemplatesForStepDerivedProcesses,
            // Process to process step
            "processStepsTemplates_ProcessTemplates" -> processStepsTemplates_ProcessTemplates,
            "processTemplatesForProcessTemplatesToProcessStep" -> processTemplatesForProcessTemplatesToProcessStep,
            "steps" -> "stepTemplates",
            "responsible" -> responsible,
            "accountable" -> accountable,
            "consulted" -> consulted,
            "informed" -> informed
          ))
      }
    })
  }
```

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with your code? What do you mean by removing the inner future? Using future.traverse will give you a `Future[Seq[ProcessStepTemplatesModel]]`, is it not what you want? 
 What is the type of `processTemplateDTO.getProessTemplatesForStepPreqrequsites(prereqTemplates)`?

Comment: What I need at the end is a `Seq[ProcessStepTemplatesModel]`
this `processTemplateDTO.getProessTemplatesForStepPreqrequsites(pr‌​ereqTemplates)` returns a `Future[Seq[ProcessTemplatesModel]]`

Comment: Any question like "removing Future", "extracting Future" doesn't make sense. Rather work/compose with ...

Comment: @Felix please note that people are less likely to help you since you seem to ask many questions, each of which follows the previous one. This suggests -- at least to me -- that you're not doing too much research and experimenting on your own. Also see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/176133

Comment: I know that Iam asking many questions in case I have have many of them ;) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working solution is:

```
Future.sequence {
        processSteps.map {
          step =>
            val prerequisiteFuture = processStepPrerequisitesDTO.getProcessStepPrerequisiteProcessTemplateIds(step.id.get)
            prerequisiteFuture.map(prereqTemplates => {
              processTemplateDTO.getProessTemplatesForStepPreqrequsites(prereqTemplates).map(pres => {
                  println("test", pres) // they are printed
                  step.stepPrerequisites = Some(pres)
                  println("test2", step)
                 step
                })
            })
        }
      }.flatMap {
        stepTemplates => {

          Future.sequence(stepTemplates).map(test =>

            Ok(Json.obj( [....]
```

Answer (score 6):

`Future.sequence`  transforms `Seq[Future[ProcessStepTemplatesModel]]` into `Future[Seq[ProcessStepTemplatesModel]]`. So if you need just `Seq[ProcessStepTemplatesModel]` you can wait till the future comes

```
Await.result({
  Future.sequence {
    processSteps.map ...
  }
}, 1 minute)
```

But whether blocking is a good idea in your situation only you can know.

---

For example here is a controller that having `List[Future[Int]]` and applying `Future.sequence` prints integers:

*/app/controllers/HomeController.scala*

```
package controllers

import javax.inject._

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._

import scala.concurrent.Future

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(cc) {

  def index() =
    Action.async {
      Future.sequence {
        List(Future(1), Future(2))
      }.map { nums =>
          Ok(views.html.index(nums))
      }
    }
}
```

*/app/views/index.scala.html*

```
@(nums: List[Int])

@main("Welcome to Play") {
  <h1>Welcome to Play!</h1>
    <ul>
    @for(num <- nums) {
        <li>@num</li>
    }
    </ul>
}
```

---

Ok, this one is more similar to yours and prints 11, 12:

```
  def index() =
    Action.async {
      Future.sequence {
        List(1, 2).map(num =>
          Future{
            Thread.sleep(5000)
            10
          }.map(n =>
            num + n
          )
        )
      }.map {
        nums =>
          Ok(views.html.index(nums))
      }
    }
```

Here

```
             step.stepPrerequisites ++Some(pres)
             step
```

I can't see how you use the value of `step.stepPrerequisites ++Some(pres)`, you return the original `step`. Are there any side effects?

Comment: Is there a solution without await?

Comment: Do you understand that your question is how to get `X` from `Future[X]`? The answer depends on what you're doing with the `X` next. Similar questions would be how to get `X` from `Option[X]` or `List[X]`.

Comment: I can imagine something like `for {res <- Future.sequence(...); ... } yield ...` depending on what you're doing.

Comment: @Felix Well, it's not the _whole_ code. It's not clear where this method is, how it will be called and what types of things inside are. It looks like a code from some controller. Does it render some page? What does this controller do now and what do you want it to do? Now it produces some  json, do you want it to produce other json?

Comment: yes exactly its a controller method. It should only return a json at the end. what it does. but not the whole one. because of the above mentioned problem. Which types did you need?

Comment: @Felix I updated my answer with simple example that hopefully helps us. Having `List[Future[Int]]` and applying `Future.sequence` it prints integers. You can modify it to use content of `Future` how you want.

Comment: yes thats not the problem. The outer map works in my example as well. But I have a more cmplex one with maps in maps

Comment: and exactly here is the problem the inner map is not finished bevore outer is sended

Comment: What I want to return is the changed step.

Comment: I use the in the outermap later. I return `"steps" -> "stepTemplates",` in the `Ok()` Just made it to string because I got an error

Comment: I've added a screenshot above

Comment: @Felix Is it true that `.map(pres => {step.stepPrerequisites ++Some(pres);  step})` can be replaced by just `.map(pres => step)`? Or are there any side effects? You calculate some value and don't use it.

Comment: @Felix Regarding type mismatch error you should check your types. I can't do it since I don't know your signatures. My example with integers shows that conceptually it should work.

Comment: `step.stepPrerequisites` is an empty `Seq[ProcessTemplatesModel]` and I will overwrite this empty seq with a new seq.

Comment: @Felix Now you see, it's quite different from your original question "I have a Seq[Future[ProcessStepTemplatesModel]] and I want to remove the inner Future".

Comment: do you maybe have time for a short teamviewer session so I can show you my code?

Comment: @Felix Github (or Bitbucket in the case of private repository) is better than teamviewer. I still think that `++` doesn't make any assignment (although it should be irrelevant to the compile error). `val s: Seq[Option[Int]] = Seq(Some(1)); s ++ Seq(Some(2))` and `s` is still `Some(1)`.

Comment: I also have tried it with `=` I think it has stored the correct value but is asynchrone

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154795/discussion-between-felix-and-dmytro-mitin).